# PyCaret ValueError - Cell is Empty

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, pycaret

I encountered an issue using PyCaret where a

```
ValueError: Cell is empty
```

is shown when I tried to create my model. Here is my code:

```
!pip install pycaret
 
from pycaret.utils import enable_colab 
enable_colab()
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

income_data = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Adult Income/train.csv')
income_data.dropna(inplace=True, axis=0)

from pycaret.classification import *

clf1 = setup(income_data, target = 'income_>50K')
lr = create_model('lr') #Returned error
```

As you can see from my code, I have already dropped cells with NaN values and during the setup, the summary also showed that I did not have any missing values in my Dataframe. For reference, the dataset I was using can be downloaded here: https://www.kaggle.com/mastmustu/income?select=train.csv

Answer (score 2):

Got this reply from the Pycaret [Github page](https://github.com/pycaret/pycaret/issues/1058), which resolved my issue:

> Hey, this is an issue with tensorflow. You need to import it after
> PyCaret:
>
> ```
> from pycaret.utils import enable_colab  
> enable_colab()
> import numpy as np 
> import pandas as pd
>
> income_data = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
> income_data.dropna(inplace=True, axis=0)
>
> from pycaret.classification import * 
> import tensorflow as tf
>
> clf1 = setup(income_data, target = 'income_>50K') lr =
> create_model('lr')
> ```
>
> This should work without issues.

Comment: In the future, please also include a link to the relevant Github issue (added); and you should accept your own answer so that the question shows as resolved and useful to others in the future.

Comment: I had the same issue with `tensorflow` and a combination of `hydra`+`hydra-submitit-plugin`. Solved it the same way by lazily importing `tensorflow`.